# command wire:poll.1000ms in jQuery

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How to execute the command ‍‍‍‍`wire: poll.10000ms` in `livewire` using jQuery code. I check inside the view with jQuery that the input value is not empty and then this command must be executed.
is it possible?

```
if (! $('#unitValue').val().length === 0) {
       //Run wire:poll.10000ms="reUnit" with Jquery code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something to add the `wire:poll.10000ms="reUnit"` onto an element in your page, but personally I would use `setInterval` to raise an `event` that `Livewire` will listen for on your `Component`.

**Livewire Component**

```php
protected $listeners = [
    'reUnit'
];

public function reUnit()
{
    // do something here
}
```

**Blade File**

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
        setInterval(() => Livewire.emit('reUnit'), 10000);
    })
</script>
```

ALl we're doing here is creating a timer that `ticks` every 10 seconds and then fires the function we've provided which in this case is a `Livewire` event.